# ec2 and haproxy, what are my options when defining server nodes, by internal/external ip?

Tags: amazon-ec2, haproxy

When setting up haproxy, you obviously have to set which web servers you want to participate in the round robin etc.

With ec2, I understand you get an internal i.p address that is randomly assigned, and you can also attach an public i.p address if you want.

If I use the internal i.p address, and for whatever reason I reboot my instance I believe I might get another internal i.p address.

What options do I have to get around this issue?

Comment: Why not use the AWS load balancers? It would be a LOT easier than any possible solutions I can see

Answer (score 0):

The internal IP should never change.

If you are worried about that you can use amazon's VPC to define your own internal subnet and which server's get what IPs on that subnet.